# Как переворачивать страницу во время создания PDF-документа?

Tags: java, .net, pdf, sdk, itext

Я хочу создать PDF-файл с альбомной ориентацией страниц. Когда я меняю формат страницы на альбомный с помощью `document.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER.rotate());`, проблема не решается. Содержимое все равно отображается слева направо, а не снизу вверх.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу создать PDF-файл с альбомной ориентацией страниц. Когда я меняю формат страницы на альбомный с помощью document.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER.rotate());, проблема не решается. Содержимое все равно отображается слева направо, а не снизу вверх.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете добиться желаемого результата в iText 7 с помощью интерфейса `EventHandler`:

```js
protected class PageRotationEventHandler implements IEventHandler {
    protected PdfNumber rotation = PORTRAIT;
    public void setRotation(PdfNumber orientation) {
        this.rotation = orientation;
    }
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        docEvent.getPage().put(PdfName.Rotate, rotation);
    } 
}
```

Используйте `PageRotationEventHandler` сразу после определения средства записи:

```js
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
PageRotationEventHandler eventHandler = new PageRotationEventHandler();
pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, eventHandler);
```

Обратите внимание, что я использую `SEASCAPE`, чтобы получить ориентацию из вашего примера.
iText7 предлагает следующие значения для вращения:

- INVERTEDPORTRAIT = `new PdfNumber(180)`;
- LANDSCAPE = new `PdfNumber(90)`;
- PORTRAIT = new `PdfNumber(0)`;
- SEASCAPE = new `PdfNumber(270)`;